# Maximum path sum of 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

My question is about [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/61a2fcac3411ca0027e71108) kata on Codewars. The function takes two sorted lists with distinct elements as arguments. These lists might or might not have common items. The task is find the maximum path sum. While finding the sum, if there any common items you can choose to change your path to the other list.

The given example is like this:

```
list1 = [0, 2, 3, 7, 10, 12]
list2 = [1, 5, 7, 8]
0->2->3->7->10->12 => 34
0->2->3->7->8      => 20
1->5->7->8         => 21
1->5->7->10->12    => 35 (maximum path)
```

I solved the kata but my code doesn't match the performance criteria so I get execution timed out. What can I do for it?

Here is my solution:

```
def max_sum_path(l1:list, l2:list):
    common_items = list(set(l1).intersection(l2))
    if not common_items:
        return max(sum(l1), sum(l2))
    common_items.sort()
    s = 0
    new_start1 = 0
    new_start2 = 0
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    for item in common_items:
        s1 = sum(itertools.islice(l1, new_start1, l1.index(item)))
        s2 = sum(itertools.islice(l2, new_start2, l2.index(item)))
        new_start1 = l1.index(item)
        new_start2 = l2.index(item)
        s += max(s1, s2)
    s1 = sum(itertools.islice(l1, new_start1, len(l1)))
    s2 = sum(itertools.islice(l2, new_start2, len(l2)))
    s += max(s1, s2)
    return s
```

Comment: First thing I would find out out which part takes most of the time by placing a few calls to `time.time`.

Comment: Like this: `start = time.time(); #do stuff that takes very long; print(time.time() - start)` - you will get the time between the two `time.time` calls in milliseconds.

Comment: when list lengths are 619 and 1352 the for loop of second code takes 0.01697850227355957 ms. When i try them for big list i notice the first one returns wrong sum. But second one works fine. But I still don't know what to do to reduce the time for long inputs.

Comment: Ah sorry … `time.time` returns seconds, not milliseconds. But that means that your code takes only 16 milliseconds - I doubt this can be reduced any further. So, either the server executing the code you submitted on that website is super-slow and takes way longer than these 16 ms, or the code determining if the code you submitted is too slow has a bug.

Comment: 0 <=len(l1), len(l2) <= 70000. Probably because of the very large input. But some people done it.

Comment: I found this in the discourse: `your solution can have a maximum time complexity of O(len(l1) + len(l2))`. No idea though how to get the time complexity of your codes … someone else has to do that.

Comment: Would `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` have an infinite path length because there is a cycle?

Comment: @fafl The problem description states that the input lists will always be sorted, presumably in the same order.

Comment: Requests to improve working code should [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com); SO is for non-working code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is actually fast, just your implementation is slow.

The two things that make it take overall O(n²) time:

- `l1.index(item)` always searches from the start of the list. Should be `l1.index(item, new_start1)`.
- `itertools.islice(l1, new_start1, ...)` creates an iterator for `l1` and **iterates over the first `new_start1` elements** before it reaches the elements you want. So just use a normal list slice instead.

Then it's just O(n log n) for the sorting and O(n) for everything else. And the sorting's O(n log n) is fast, might easily take less time than the O(n) part for any allowed input and even larger ones.

Here's the rewritten version, gets accepted in about 6 seconds, just like the solutions from the other answers.

```
def max_sum_path(l1:list, l2:list):
    common_items = list(set(l1).intersection(l2))
    if not common_items:
        return max(sum(l1), sum(l2))
    common_items.sort()
    s = 0
    new_start1 = 0
    new_start2 = 0
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    for item in common_items:
        next_start1 = l1.index(item, new_start1)  # changed
        next_start2 = l2.index(item, new_start2)  # changed
        s1 = sum(l1[new_start1 : next_start1])    # changed
        s2 = sum(l2[new_start2 : next_start2])    # changed
        new_start1 = next_start1                  # changed
        new_start2 = next_start2                  # changed
        s += max(s1, s2)
    s1 = sum(l1[new_start1:])                     # changed
    s2 = sum(l2[new_start2:])                     # changed
    s += max(s1, s2)
    return s
```

Or you could use iterators instead of indexes. Here's your solution rewritten to do that, also gets accepted in about 6 seconds:

```
def max_sum_path(l1:list, l2:list):
    common_items = sorted(set(l1) & set(l2))
    s = 0
    it1 = iter(l1)
    it2 = iter(l2)
    for item in common_items:
        s1 = sum(iter(it1.__next__, item))
        s2 = sum(iter(it2.__next__, item))
        s += max(s1, s2) + item
    s1 = sum(it1)
    s2 = sum(it2)
    s += max(s1, s2)
    return s
```

I'd combine the last four lines into one, just left it like you had so it's easier to compare.

Answer (score 4):

The problem says "aim for linear time complexity", which is a pretty big hint that things like nested loops won't fly (`index` are nested O(n) loops here and `sort()` is O(n log(n)) when there are many duplicate values between the input lists).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70230306/6243352) shows how you can cache the repeated `.index` calls and use start offsets from the last chunk to bring the complexity down.

As the linked answer also states, `itertools.islice` isn't appropriate here because it traverses from the start of the list. Instead, use native slicing. This, coupled with the modifications to `index` above, gives you linearithmic complexity overall, linear on most input.

---

For context, here's my approach, which isn't that different from yours, although I cache indices and avoid sorting.

I started by formulating the problem as a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) with the idea of searching for the maximum path sum:

```
       +---> [0, 2, 3] ---+            +---> [10, 12]
[0] ---|                  |---> [7] ---|
       +---> [1, 5] ------+            +---> [8]
```

We might as well also sum the values of each node for clarity:

```
     +---> 5 ---+          +---> 22
0 ---|          |---> 7 ---|
     +---> 6 ---+          +---> 8
```

The diagram above reveals that a greedy solution will be optimal, given the uniqueness constraints. For example, starting from the root, we can only pick the 5 or 6 value path to get to 7. The larger of the two, 6, is guaranteed to be part of the maximum-weight path, so we take it.

Now, the question is only how to implement this logic. Going back to the lists, here's a more substantial input with formatting and annotations to help motivate an approach:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8,    10,         14, 15    ]
[      4,    8, 9,     11, 12,     15, 90]
       ^     ^                      ^
       |     |                      |
```

This illustrates how the linked indices line up. Our goal is to iterate over each chunk between the links, taking the larger of the two sublist sums:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8,    10,         14, 15    ]
[      4,    8, 9,     11, 12,     15, 90]
 ^~~^     ^     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^      ^^
  0       1             2               3  <-- chunk number
```

The expected result for the above input should be 3 + 4 + 7 + 8 + 32 + 15 + 90 = 159, taking all of the link values plus the top list's sublist sum for chunks 0 and 1 and the bottom list for chunks 2 and 3.

Here's a rather verbose, but hopefully easy to understand, implementation; you can visit the thread to see more elegant solutions:

```py
def max_sum_path(a, b):
    b_idxes = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(b)}
    link_to_a = {}
    link_to_b = {}
    
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
        if e in b_idxes:
            link_to_a[e] = i
            link_to_b[e] = b_idxes[e]
    
    total = 0
    start_a = 0
    start_b = 0
    
    for link in link_to_a: # dicts assumed sorted, Python 3.6+
        end_a = link_to_a[link]
        end_b = link_to_b[link]
        total += max(sum(a[start_a:end_a]), sum(b[start_b:end_b])) + link
        start_a = end_a + 1
        start_b = end_b + 1
        
    return total + max(sum(a[start_a:]), sum(b[start_b:]))
```

Comment: I think your first paragraph is misleading. Neither `sum` nor "`slice`" (not sure what exactly you mean) nor `sort` are the problem (see my answer for the actual problems and solutions that still do their sum/slice/sort and are fast).

Comment: I'm not saying that these functions are inherently of these complexities or that you can't use them to solve the problem (I'm clearly using slices), it's that in OP's code, the functions as they're being used _are_ of these complexities. Emphasis should be on the word "here" in that sentence, referring to the way OP's using them. For example, `common_items.sort()` is O(n) because `common_items` might be all of the elements in both lists! Whether the CW test suite actually tests this edge case or not is unclear (the nested slices/`sum`s are probably the biggest issue).

Comment: But not even "here" they're the problem. The do "fly" here. The biggest time waster is the `index` calls, and the other is not the "slice" but the hidden running to the slice.

Comment: Sure, there's a difference between complexity and what the Codewars solution actually tests. Once again, if the complexity looks bad on paper but the CW test suite doesn't really push the code on edge cases like the one I mentioned, then we count ourselves lucky. But on a timeout without any info, it's safest to assume these cases are being tested and try to ensure it's genuinely linear. Looking again at OP's code, it's not as bad as I thought (the `sum`s/slices are OK, for example), so I'll revise my post. Thanks.

Comment: But even the complexity is not the problem. In my answer I'm still using their exact algorithm, including sum/slice/sort, and it's overall O(n) except for the sorting's O(n log n), which has a small hidden constant (so might even be faster than the O(n) part for any allowed input).

Comment: Again, their complexity is only "not the problem" because of the way CW's tests are designed -- essentially luck that they're not really pushing the code. I could easily design large tests with a high density of dupes that would ensure a genuinely linear solution.

Comment: I'd like to see one of those tests.

Comment: Good point, I can't seem to cause any performance problems for it, even with a large input of duplicates to try to get a worst-case scenario. Basically, when I saw the timeouts I didn't bother messing with OP's code, but it turns out caching `.index()`, using the offset to `.index()`, and using native slicing pretty much gives a reasonable solution. Kudos for not throwing the baby out with the bathwater -- I overestimated the impact of sorting. Answer is updated to mention all of this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also trying to make the sorting the problem. Like with `l1 = l2 = sorted(random.sample(range(2**30), 70_000))`, i.e., all values common, and chosen from a much larger range so that the set doesn't sort them already. On that input, the first solution in my answer seems to spend only about 20% of its time on the sorting.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that they're all distinct numbers makes the sorting run faster. Also, it's native code so, yeah, it shouldn't be a big issue. Sometimes linearithmic can be a real bottleneck, but not here apparently.

Comment: Hmm, how would distinct numbers make the sorting *faster*?

Comment: I'm trying to think in terms of branch prediction and implementation details of Timsort -- one thing is that if you `print(common_items)` on submission, you'll see that it's often sorted, or near-sorted. Generally speaking, sorting is linear when nearly-sorted (insertion sort, for example). From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort): "...It is designed to be very fast in cases where the slice is nearly sorted, or consists of two or more sorted sequences concatenated one after another." So I think my point about avoiding sorting still has theoretical merit.

Comment: Those cases where it's nearly sorted are cases of high density, right? An extreme case is where the n items are the numbers from 0 to n-1, in which case the set *completely* sorts them ([demo](https://tio.run/##LYw7DoAgEET7PcWW0JFYaMNZDAmgJPyyrIWnx9VYTWbey/Sbz1aXrdOckVpBctVLpNIbMY7zijEHAIcWcxqshB9BrWY3xmgNv6CcBuiUKqvPGoFl0mgtDvkJ/m1zPg)). Try `print(common_items)` with my input `l1 = l2 = sorted(random.sample(range(2**30), 70_000))`, that should look pretty shuffled.

Comment: @KellyBundy's test case *is* bad for the sorting solution, but I'd say rather because of the other heavy work for each value, and ggorlen's solution is even a bit slower. See my [benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70241500/1672429) answer.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely misjudged this a bit. My answer uses multiple passes and data structures with higher overhead, dicts instead of lists (I wasn't really going for speed, just linear complexity and clarity), and in the end this turns out to be more problematic than the dominant sorting complexity.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in a single pass in `O(n)` runtime and `O(1)` space complexity. All you need is two pointers to traverse both arrays in parallel and two path values.

You increment the pointer to the smaller element and add its value to its path. When you find a common element, you add it to both paths and then set both paths to the max value.

```
def max_sum_path(l1, l2):
    path1 = 0
    path2 = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(l1) and j < len(l2):
        if l1[i] < l2[j]:
            path1 += l1[i]
            i += 1
        elif l2[j] < l1[i]:
            path2 += l2[j]
            j += 1
        else:
            # Same element in both paths
            path1 += l1[i]
            path2 += l1[i]
            path1 = max(path1, path2)
            path2 = path1
            i += 1
            j += 1
    while i < len(l1):
        path1 += l1[i]
        i += 1
    while j < len(l2):
        path2 += l2[j]
        j += 1
    return max(path1, path2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you know the items shared between the two lists, you can iterate over each list separately to sum up the items in between the shared items, thus constructing a list of partial sums. These lists will have the same length for both input lists, because the number of shared items is the same.

The maximum path sum can then be found by taking the maximum between the two lists for each stretch between shared values:

```py
def max_sum_path(l1, l2):
    shared_items = set(l1) & set(l2)
    
    def partial_sums(lst):
        result = []
        partial_sum = 0
        for item in lst:
            partial_sum += item
            if item in shared_items:
                result.append(partial_sum)
                partial_sum = 0
        result.append(partial_sum)
        return result
            
    return sum(map(max, partial_sums(l1), 
                        partial_sums(l2)))
```

Time complexity: We only iterate once over each list (the iteration over the shorter lists of partial sums is irrelevant here), so this code is linear in the length of the input lists. However, as you and Kelly Bundy have noted, your own algorithm actually has the same time complexity, except for the sorting the common items part, which does not appear to be too relevant for the given test cases.

So as a general conclusion, if your goal is just to make your code fast enough for passing certain test cases, it can be better to profile the execution to find the time sinks in the actual implementation rather than worry about theoretical worst case scenarios.

Comment: Could also return `sum(map(max, partial_sums1, partial_sums2))`.

Comment: I don't think the sorting is a problem, it's only done once and its hidden constant is rather fast. With or without `sorted(shared_items)`, this takes about 5.8 seconds on the site (with the ATTEMPT button).

Comment: my approach to the problem is like this:
find common items. if none return max sum l1,l2.
if any then go through until them and sum up.
at common item select max of it and add to sum.
when finish select max of partial sums.
i think the problem is "sum(itertools.islice(l1, new_start1, l1.index(item)))"
instead i should be doing it through iterating linear and adding up for each list.

Comment: Thanks @KellyBundy for pointing out the real problem with the OP's code. I upvoted your answer and edited my own to mention your point, and I changed the return statement as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks @ÜmitKara for the additional information. This helped me to edit my answer.

Comment: I'd say sorting is not just too relevant for the "given" test cases but for any allowed test cases. If I optimize the rest of the code and use a worst case for sorting, the (link too long...) ...

Comment: ... [sorting still takes less than 20% of the whole time](https://tio.run/##dVPbTsMwDH3vV/gFkcAYbSYEqrQvQaiqaMoi5VIlngAhvn3YScsYgz60ie1zfHzp9I674DcPUzwcxhgcoHHaIBg3hYgw6LHfW@zYGqFP2R2rHBl7P9Bnjky9m6yuKkKA69@6tHfd1ONO2Ka1JuEKrMoH2VZAz3NwLvjOoHYJtsAekTRSuFwbjzom/YwmeGGVlBlhRvABT4CFip@ocR89ZxaUmVlWkA8LGmvKktULeSZgnaiE2Y7Nr0CWVxcF7DLq@574no730fihWeUPG21DlQz6jUsvpxIVInBWMP6fYgpvLuORcrYg@L0t/IKDV6RFyid5hKgFoh5JIUPUAlELRJ1C4HpbGkaak5LVeep2Dj9l/7b@RTAPgrp4Qz2vKsuENuOpx3oQZVEEbc@LFurqalPTqO7rrq5rGhU3p@POFP/dvC1n02OyvJWw/b1u3O5/Rvm6C1YvsEUiO6ZIOyfGy48j7@2P6HbdXHxCGAF3upgzLbzSH5Em7RGCz5KMf1lfysPhCw).

Answer (score 3):

**Benchmarks**

On the [Discourse](https://www.codewars.com/kata/61a2fcac3411ca0027e71108/discuss/python) tab you can click "Show Kata Test Cases" (once you solved the kata) to see their test case generator. I used that to benchmark the solutions posted so far as well as one from me. A few dozen rounds, since the test cases are pretty random, causing big runtime fluctuation. In each round, all test cases generated were given to all solutions (so in each round, all solutions got the same test cases).

[image: Test cases from Codewars]

And also Kelly Bundy's worst case for sorting the set of common values:

[image]

Code shall follow.